# Exposed filters and how data can be styled

Tags: views

We have a drupal site that we are customizing. We have a set of filters that are exposed on a page. This works perfectly, i.e. when a filter option is selected only the results are correctly shown. But we have a client requirement that upon selecting one of the filter options the whole results should be shown (as if no filtering was applied) but only the valid results should be clickable and the other should have some disabled class.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?