# Style different exposed filter options based on query results

Tags: views

I have an exposed filter that displays a list of checkboxes. When you select one, I'd like the options that are no longer represented in the query to have a sort of "disabled" look. I could make it work if I could simply apply a class to those options, but I can't find a way to do so.

I've used and edited the views_filters_selective module (a part of views_hacks) and found I can change which options display by overriding the class "views_handler_filter_in_operator" and the function "get_value_options," but I don't seem to have access to the way that Drupal renders the array, nor can I apply any html classes. I think it's due to a misunderstanding of themes (in which I'm inexperienced), but I have no clue where to start.

Should I edit the form which displays the options, or do I have to edit the way that drupal renders the array? If the second is the case: how can I send, from the handler, the information needed to determine which checkboxes should be "disabled?" Where would I start?

This is similar to this question: [Exposed filters and how data can be styled](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/41549/29129) which no one answered.